# In eclipse .h File not recognizing struct written in other .h file

Tags: c, eclipse, struct

In TCB.h I declared a struct, in q.h I called the TCB struct and allocated memory for it. I included TCB.h.  However in q.h it is not recognizing my struct.

TCB.h

```
struct TCB_t
{
    struct TCB_t * next;
    struct TCB_t * previous;
    ucontext_t context;
    int val;
};
```

q.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include "TCB.h"


struct TCB_t *queue = NULL;

void create_list()
{
    queue =  (struct TCB_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct TCB_t));
    queue->next;  //this is where I am getting the error
}
```

Comment: What error, exactly, are you getting?

Comment: Field 'next' could not be resolved

Comment: your code looks Ok, try clean your project and then run a build again

Comment: I deleted q.h and recreated the file now it works.

Comment: what is the create_list() function doing in a header file? did you mean q.c in your comment?

Comment: what is this data instance: struct TCB_t *queue = NULL; doing in a header file?  did you mean q.c in your comment, regarding which file is being listed?

Comment: this line: queue->next;  is not a valid C statement.  Maybe you meant: queue = queue->next; or queue->next = NULL;